# How to push a package from a flight to a submission using UWP Microsoft Store Services API

Tags: uwp, windows-store, cicd, msix

We are building a UWP application. We already have the first version of the CI/CD pipeline. The pipeline does the following

1. Builds the `*.msixupload` bundle
2. Pushes it to the package flight called "Staging" for internal testing

The thing it doesn't currently do is automate the release of the app. Every time our QAs are done testing and we want to push the app from Staging to the production environment we do the following

1. We open the UWP partner center
2. Select the production submission and click update
3. We update the necessary release notes and screenshots if needed
4. For the package, we select a package that we had inside the "Staging" flight. We actually do not upload a new package, which I think makes sense - you want to release the build that was already tested and you do not actually want to rebuild the app for production with a different version

The problem is that I can't find a way to automate the 4th step. [In this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/csharp-code-examples-for-the-windows-store-submission-api) you can see a flow for creating a new submission. However, it actually involves re-uploading an `*.msixupload` bundle. I can't find a sample that would mimic what we are doing - instead of uploading a new bundle we select an existing bundle from a package flight.

Is there a way to create a new submission using a previously published package from another flight without having to upload a new bundle through the API?

P.S.

You can't re-upload the same bundle with the same version to the new submission that was previously used inside the package flight. It will result in a conflict error. So, you will have to rebuild a new package, which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a new submission using a previously published package from another flight without having to upload a new bundle through the API?

I have to say that there is no way the get the bundle you uploaded from the package flight back once you've uploaded it. I understand your requirement but currently, there is no such API that could do it even in the partner center dashboard website. You still need to upload a new bundle for submission.

Comment: Thanks, Roy for the answer. But I can do that from the Partner center. Essentially, you select the package source to be the "Alpha" package flight, and it brings the package that was already uploaded into the public submission. I would assume that Partner Center uses the same set of APIs. If it's possible in the partner center why wouldn't it be possible with teh APIs?

Comment: @kyurkchyan The submission API is just designed for simple general submission scenarios like automatic upload for an existing package file. You could submit a feature request in the Feedback Hub if you want to add this feature.

Comment: Thanks Roy. We really wanted to have a fully automated deployment process without manual intervention. One last question before I give up. I understand that the only way is uploading a package from scratch. Is there a way to overcome the "Conflict" that's caused by uploading a duplicate bundle? I can see the following options
1. Somehow deleting it from the package flight before pushing it to the public submission
2. Somehow changing the version of the *.msixupload without having to rebuild the package so it's not actually a duplicate
Or perhaps some other strategy that you could suggest?

Comment: Thanks Roy. That makes sense. Really appreciate your support.  Our build of UWP takes about 30 minutes. It would be really cool if we could change the version number inside the msixupload without having to rebuild the app. Is there any tool that can do that?
I know this is a different question, perhaps I should ask it in a separate thread.

Comment: @kyurkchyan ops, I missed one thing, there is a delete function in the package flight submission API. Here it is:[Delete a package flight submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/delete-a-flight-submission)

Comment: @kyurkchyan You could try this to make sure if the flight submission could be deleted and then try to upload the same package to the Store. This should work to avoid the Conflict issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roy. I will play with it. BTW, I just tried re-uploading the same package that existed in the Flight to the Store, and it didn't cause conflict on the Portal. Perhaps, it works with API. But I do believe that I have seen conflict, perhaps I have done something wrong. Anyway, for the current thread all is nice and clean. Thanks again for the support.